# ci_csrf_token was set to ” onmouseover=prompt(XSS) bad=”

Tags: codeigniter, xss, csrf, codeigniter-2, penetration-testing

i used ci_csrf_token hidden field in my forms.but any form in my script get alert with Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner.

alert details :

> > > Cookie input ci_csrf_token was set to " onmouseover=prompt(965267) bad="
> > >       The input is reflected inside a tag element between double quotes.

in view source:

> <input type="hidden" name="ci_csrf_token" value="\\" onmouseover=prompt(965267) bad=\"" />

can anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to html attribute encode the token before you put it into the hidden field. Do you add it to the form on the client side or the server side? If you do it on the server side, you may want to do input validation to make sure the token is on the expected format.

Comment: Codeigniter adds the token automatically.

Comment: i cheked in form validation by: $this->form_validation->set_rules('ci_csrf_token','required|trim|xss_clean|escape'); but its not work and not solved...

Comment: we should find a solution for Preventing of change this token.